# Image processing pipeline: Flat field correction

Tags: image, image-processing

Where would be the right place, in the image processing pipeline, to perform flat-field correction? Should it be done on the bayared image right after subtracting the dark-frame or should it be done after unbayering or after color correction?

Thanks

Gilad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bayer filtering depends on the geometry of the pixels and their color filters, so it needs to come before anything that would upset that geometry. Likewise with the dark-frame subtraction.

It won't interfere with color correction at all, or vice versa, so it's your choice if it comes before or after.